# Yii2 - How to include html on multiple pages

Tags: php, yii, yii2

Ordinarily if I wanted to include some common code on multiple pages I would use something like:

```
<?php include_once(__DIR__.'/../someFolder/SomeFile.php' ?>
```

Just wondering what the preferred way to do this is in Yii2?
I have looked at Widgets and Partial views but haven't really been able to conclude this is the best way to factorise common code between pages. I can provide more info, just not sure what too.

Came across this: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-views.html#rendering-in-widgets is it likely to be where I should be looking?

Answer (score 1):

Seems I have answered my own question.

```
<?= \Yii::$app->view->renderFile('@app/views/site/fileToInclude.php'); ?>
```

If someone can add to this, that would be fantastic, but this seems to answer my question.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can do the following: `view->renderpartial` or just `view->render`

For example you can use this: `<?= \Yii::$app->view->render('fileToInclude', ['id' => $somevariables]); ?>` if it is in the same folder for example